# Reusable button component using React Typescript with Tailwind and ESLint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, tailwind-css, eslint

I'm currently building a project using React Typescript with Tailwind and ESLint. Each of them is new to me, and I'm mainly trying to understand the basics of Typescript and ESLint (because they are the ones I have the most problems with). I created a button that includes an icon and a caption inside the button, but then I decided to make this button a reusable component. I tried doing it myself by refering to the component I did in the past using regular JS, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I found an article by sujaykundu at [https://sujaykundu.com/blog/creating-a-reusable-button-component-in-react-typescript-and-tailwind/](https://stackoverflow.com) about creating such a component but it didn't include ESLint. He gave there the code to create such a component. I wanted to see it in action first and then customize it to my needs, but as soon as I copy-pasted it into my VSC ESLint started yelling at me that: *Function component is not a function declaration* even though it wasn't meant to be a function but a constant instead. It also led me to a page with an explanation: [https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/function-component-definition.md](https://stackoverflow.com)

Here's the code I used:

```
import React from 'react';

// interface to declare all our prop types
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onClick: () => void;
  variant?: string, // default, primary, info, success, warning, danger, dark
  size?: string, // sm, md, lg
  disabled?: boolean;
}

// button component, consuming props
const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({
  children,
  onClick,
  variant = 'default',
  size = 'md',
  disabled,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={`btn ${variant} ${size}` + (disabled ? ' disabled' : '')}
      onClick={onClick}
      disabled={disabled}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

After reading the *Examples of correct code for this rule* on the page with explanation I understood that I was in fact using an arrow function and I tried to modify the code according to this explanation:

```
// only arrow functions for named components
// [2, { "namedComponents": "arrow-function" }]
const Component = (props) => {
  return <div />;
};
```

So I modified the constant like this:

```
const Button = (React.FC<Props>) => ({
```

But still leaving the second arrow in it's place, but then I received several errors like: *Property 'FC' does not exist on type 'typeof React'.ts(2339)* or *Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)*

I tried modifying the code based on other explanations of the rule, I tried getting it to work by using trial and error, I tried using hints from other articles or tutorials, but always ended up with either the code being written completely incorrectly or ESLint underlining much of it for me.
Can anyone help me making this code work?
Also my eslint config below:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended',
    'plugin:tailwindcss/recommended',
  ],
  overrides: [],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint', 'prettier', 'jsx-a11y', 'tailwindcss'],
  rules: {
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 0,
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'react/require-default-props': 0,
    'max-classes-per-file': 0,
    'tailwindcss/no-custom-classname': 0,
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 0,
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'warn',
      {
        endOfLine: 'crlf',
      },
      {usePrettierrc: true},
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`Function component is not a function declaration` means that you can't use `const A = () => {}` to declare a component, you have to use `function A() {}`